# Programmatically toggle checkboxes

Tags: javascript, blackberry, mobile-website

How to toggle (check/uncheck) checkboxes on Blackberry 4.6 web browser using Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In BlackBeey 4.6 browser, the DOM is read-only, so this can't be done.

Answer (score 3):

BlackBerry 4.6 fully supports DOM level 2 and ECMA-262 3rd edition ([source](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11844/Feature_JavaScript_512506_11.jsp)), so it's probably the same way you do it in any other browser:

```
// Using boolean negation
var check = document.getElementById("somecheckbox");
check.checked = !check.checked;

// Using bitwise XOR
document.getElementById("somecheckbox").checked ^= 1;
```

Comment: You need to remove the `.checked` from the end of the first line of code.

Comment: @Tim: I copied and pasted it from my bitwise XOR example without paying much attention lol.  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to a Blackberry browser to test this on, but you should be able to do something like:

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('myCheck');
checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
```